# How to write ODBC connection string for Snowflake

Tags: c#, .net-core, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I write an ODBC connection string for Snowflake? I can't seem to figure it out. Below is the sample code I put together in .NET Core:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace SnowflakeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            string connetionString = null;
            OdbcConnection cnn;
            connetionString = "Driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};Server=xxxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com;Database=SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA;User=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx";
            cnn = new OdbcConnection(connetionString);

            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Console.Write("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("Can not open connection ! " + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try uid instead of User and pwd instead of Password

Comment: @AngryHacker. still no luck. it gave me the same error. "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: I added an answer on how to build your connection string.

Comment: I finally figured it out. @AngryHacker's suggestion is actually correct. Please use Uid and Pwd instead. The root cause of the failure is the version of the snowflake odbc driver. So many people suggest using the one with 32-bit version because Visual Studio is 32-bit application. But actually install 64-bit one resolve my issue. i can now build the connection.Hope it will help others.

Comment: I also figured out why 32-bit did not work for me. Because i used .net core, and my OS is 64-bit, therefore i should use 64-bit one. if anyone uses .net framework, i think he or she might consider using 32-bit one.

Comment: VS is a 32-bit app, true, but when you press Run, it runs under whatever bitness you specified your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can build an ODBC connection.

1. Create a file on the desktop, called `foo.udl`.  Double Click on it
2. In the `Provider` tab, select `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers'
3. In the `Connection` tab, click `Use connection string`, then the 'Build` button.
4. Under `Machine Data Source` pick your driver, then fill out the rest (e.g. user & password).
5. Then click OK.
6. Open the file in Notepad and boom - there is your connection string.

Comment: Thanks for putting it together. It looks really promising at the beginning. However, it cannot build the connection string for me. And gives error "Operation cannot be executed because an error occured during connection to the driver" . But it indeed gave me some hint and helped me figure out the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to enter this connection string:

```
connetionString = "Driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};Server={accountid}.snowflakecomputing.com;Database=SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA;uid=xxxxxxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxxx";
```

Answer (score 0):

[ODBC Configuration and Connection Parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/odbc/odbc-parameters#connection-parameters)

> **Required Connection Parameters**
>
> - name (Data Source)
> - port (Port)
>
>   - You do not need to change the default Port value of 443.
> - pwd (Password)
> - server (Server)
> - uid (User)
>
> **Optional Connection Parameters**
>
> - CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE=Boolean
> - database (Database)
> - role (Role)
> - schema (Schema)
> - SecondaryRoles (Role)
> - tracing (Tracing)
> - warehouse (Warehouse)

Related: [ODBC Driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/client-redirect#odbc-driver)

Answer (score 0):

I'm coding in Excel, with the VBA project unlocked, so don't want to use an UID/PWD combination.

If you're in my situation, I was able to drop the PWD and added "Authenticator=ExternalBrowser;" in its place, then use Windows API to get current user's login followed by "@" and our domain, and use it for the UID. The user will see a web browser (tab) open briefly only on the first call. I'm assuming there's a token being given that lasts for some time, though I've not tested how long - likely a setting by the DB Admins.

Here's my full function:

```
Public Function sSnowflakeCnxnStr() As String   
    sSnowflakeCnxnStr = Replace("Driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};" _
    & "Server=OurDBServer.snowflakecomputing.com;" _
    & "Database=OurDB_
    & "Schema=OurSchema;" _
    & "Authenticator=ExternalBrowser;" _
    & "UID=<UserName>@OurDomain.com" _
    , "<UserName>", GetUserName)
End Function
```

Where GetUserName is a wrapper for the API call:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function wu_GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" _
    (ByVal lpbuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Function GetUserName() As String
    Dim sUserName As String
    Dim lLength As Long
    Dim lResult As Long

    '-- Set up the buffer
    sUserName = String$(255, 0)
    lLength = 255

    '-- Make the call
    lResult = wu_GetUserName(sUserName, lLength)

    '-- Clean up and Assign the value
    GetUserName = Left(sUserName, InStr(1, sUserName, Chr(0)) - 1)
End Function
```

I've barely started using it, but was able to pull the full list of tables in the DB so it seems to be working.

Also: For 32-bit Excel, I had to install the 32-bit SnowFlake driver.